# Проблема с библиотекой libcurl. Не компилируется программа на Linux

Tags: c++, linux, curl, arm, mime

Здравствуйте, проблема с компиляцией программы на OS Linux Ubuntu, ОС стоит на плате odroid-xu4, с ARM процессором. Библиотеку подключил, ругается только на функции mime, в чём может быть причина? Задача вообще состоит в передаче изображения на сервер.
Спасибо за любую помощь в решении данного вопроса.

```
droid@odroid:~/Desktop/curl_test.2$ g++ -o postit2 postit2.c -lcurl
/tmp/cc4MoKQE.o: In function `main':
postit2.c:(.text+0x2c): undefined reference to `curl_mime_init'
postit2.c:(.text+0x36): undefined reference to `curl_mime_addpart'
postit2.c:(.text+0x48): undefined reference to `curl_mime_name'
postit2.c:(.text+0x56): undefined reference to `curl_mime_filedata'
postit2.c:(.text+0xfa): undefined reference to `curl_mime_free'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
odroid@odroid:~/Desktop/curl_test.2$ curl --version
curl 7.56.0 (armv7l-unknown-linux-gnueabihf) libcurl/7.47.0 
OpenSSL/1.0.2g zlib/1.2.8 libidn/1.32 librtmp/2.3
Release-Date: 2017-10-04
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps ldap ldaps 
pop3 pop3s rtmp rtsp smb smbs smtp smtps telnet tftp 
Features: AsynchDNS IDN IPv6 Largefile GSS-API Kerberos SPNEGO NTLM 
NTLM_WB SSL libz TLS-SRP UnixSockets


#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <curl/curl.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
CURL *curl;
CURLcode res;

curl_mime *form = NULL;
curl_mimepart *field = NULL;
struct curl_slist *headerlist = NULL;
static const char buf[] = "Expect:";

curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);

curl = curl_easy_init();
if(curl) {
/* Create the form */ 
form = curl_mime_init(curl);

/* Fill in the file upload field */ 
field = curl_mime_addpart(form);
curl_mime_init(field, "img.jpeg");
curl_mime_filedata(field, "img.jpeg");

/* Fill in the filename field */ 
field = curl_mime_addpart(form);
curl_mime_name(field, "img.jpeg");
curl_mime_data(field, "img.jpeg", CURL_ZERO_TERMINATED);

/*Fill in the submit field too, even if this is rarely needed */ 
field = curl_mime_addpart(form);
curl_mime_name(field, "img.jpeg");
curl_mime_data(field, "img.jpeg", CURL_ZERO_TERMINATED);

/* initialize custom header list (stating that Expect: 100-continue is not
   wanted */ 
headerlist = curl_slist_append(headerlist, buf);
/* what URL that receives this POST */ 
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://auto-face.meral.com.ua/device.savepoint");
if((argc == 2) && (!strcmp(argv[1], "noexpectheader")))
  /* only disable 100-continue header if explicitly requested */ 
  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, headerlist);
 curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_MIMEPOST, form);

/* Perform the request, res will get the return code */ 
  res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
/* Check for errors */ 
if(res != CURLE_OK)
  fprintf(stderr, "curl_easy_perform() failed: %s\n",
          curl_easy_strerror(res));


res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
/* always cleanup */ 
curl_easy_cleanup(curl);

/* then cleanup the form */ 
curl_mime_free(form);
/* free slist */ 
curl_slist_free_all(headerlist);
}
 return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Проверяйте внимательнее версии библиотек и когда функции появились.

Функции `curl_mime_*` появились в `libcurl` *вчера*. Буквально вчера. Набор изменений предложен [29 августа](https://github.com/curl/curl/pull/1839), принят в мастер 2 сентября, первый и пока единственный [релиз](https://curl.haxx.se/changes.html) за номером версии `7.56.0` с этими функциями выпущен 4 октября.